# Cypress.io custom command 'TypeError is not a function'

Tags: cypress

I'm getting an error when using a custom command I've added to my /support/commands.js file.
What is worth mentioning, all others custom commands I've added work fine.

I've followed some other solutions others have mentioned on this forum but none have helped.
I've restarted both VSCode and Cypress.io to no avail.

My cypress.json file is as follows (I'm missing my projectId, where do I find it?):

```
{
  "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.js"
}
```

Cypress code:

```
    // verify the stepper header
    cy.verifyStepperHeader()
```

custom command:

```
  // verify the stepper header
  Cypress.Commands.add('verifyStepperHeader', () => {
    cy.get('.stepper-header').scrollIntoView()
      .should('be.visible').within(() => {
      cy.contains('User Targets').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Data Upload').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Data Quality').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Sensor Mapping').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Tuning Mode').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Tuning').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Tuning Results').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Validation').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Validation Results').should('be.visible')
      cy.contains('Summary').should('be.visible')
      })
  })
```

I've also got

```
    // Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
    import './commands'
```

in my index.js file which I think is the default.

Comment: The Project Id can be found after you've set up the project to record. docs.cypress.io/guides/dashboard/projects#Project-ID